# MissingMethodException with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make SQLite work to store some information locally and by now I've encountered an annoying issue: whenever I call the sqlite function CreateTable it gives me back an exception.

Here's the exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: string SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_column_name(SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt,int).
```

Here's the Interface I used to make it cross-platform:

```
public interface IDataBase
{
    SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
}
```

The Android implementation:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DataBase))]
namespace MyNameSpace.Droid
{
    public class DataBase : IDataBase
    {
        public DataBase() { }
        public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var fileName = "DataBase.db3";
            string docsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string path = Path.Combine(docsPath, fileName);
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
            return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

And the one for iOs:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DataBase))]
namespace MyNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class DataBase : IDataBase
    {
        public DataBase() { }
        public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var fileName = "DataBase.db3";
            var docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var libraryPath = Path.Combine(docPath, "..", "Library");
            var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, fileName);
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
            return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have my Table type:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.DataBase
{
     public class MacroCategoria
     {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string descrizione { get; set; }

        public MacroCategoria() { }

    }
}
```

The DataBase controller and I method that gets the first element:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.DataBase
{
    public class DBController
    {
        static object locker = new object();
        SQLiteConnection database;

        public DBController()
        {
            database = DependencyService.Get<IDataBase>().GetConnection();
            if (database != null)
            {
                database.CreateTable<MacroCategoria>();
                database.Insert(new MacroCategoria() { ID = 0, descrizione = "Description" });
            }
        }

        public MacroCategoria getFirstMacro()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (database.Table<MacroCategoria>().Count() == 0)
                    return null;
                else
                    return database.Table<MacroCategoria>().First();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Which is called in the App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static DBController dbController;
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    [...Other Default Methods...]

    public static DBController DBController
    {
        get
        {
            if(dbController == null)
            {
                dbController = new DBController();
            }
            return dbController;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, when in my mainPage i have a function that's supposed to get the first element:

```
private void CartIcon_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        App.DBController.getFirstMacro();

    } catch(Exception ex) { throw; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to add SQLitePCL.Raw packages.